# Adobe AIR Updater Problem

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, air, adobe

i just wanted to update an AIR Application for a client. But when the update framework (i'm using the ApplicationUpdaterUI) has downloaded the AIR file and wants to install it, it says that the AIR file is damaged. When i'm installing the downloaded file (copied it from the #ApplicationUpdate dir) by hand everything works fine. Wiredly enough, everything worked fine the last time.

Any idea what maybe be the cause to this problem?

Adobe AIR 2.0.2.12610
App compiled with Flex 4.0

Thanks in advance

Edit: This is whats in the Logfile when the updating process fails:

```
[2010-09-01:14:09:20] Starting update of c:\programme\myapp\myapp.exe
[2010-09-01:14:09:20] Updating from file:///C:/Dokumente%20und%20Einstellungen/VAdmin/Anwendungsdaten/myapp.4BCA79BE2D83E8B0AFDB124EAD7E123E1B6A1E28.1/Local%20Store/%23ApplicationUpdater/update.air
[2010-09-01:14:09:20] Updating to version 0.9.509
[2010-09-01:14:09:20] UI SWF load is complete
[2010-09-01:14:09:21] UI initialized
[2010-09-01:14:09:21] beginning UI styling
[2010-09-01:14:09:21] UI styling complete
[2010-09-01:14:09:21] Unpackaging to C:\Dokumente und Einstellungen\VAdmin\Lokale Einstellungen\Temp\fla1E6.tmp
[2010-09-01:14:09:21] failed while unpackaging: [IOErrorEvent type="ioError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2032" errorID=2032]
```

Timo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everyone interested in the solution:
I was doing this:

```
            try {
                for each (var win:NativeWindow in NativeApplication.nativeApplication.openedWindows) {
                    winClosingEvent = new Event(Event.CLOSING, false, true);
                    win.dispatchEvent(winClosingEvent);
                    if (!winClosingEvent.isDefaultPrevented()) {
                        win.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (e:Error) {
            }
```

when i was closing my application. After removing this source it worked.... again. Still, i have no idea why this seems to break the air app now.

Comment: ha-ha, i think that updater was child window of main window too in some sense, and you just killed them all before closing) or in another way dispatcher will call file cleaner too, anyway thanks for sharing this)

Answer (score 0):

its hard to say, but seems to be that current AIR release is buggy, anyway check [this](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/403/kb403150.html#main_Windows_Vista__2032_stream_error___Trying_to_install_from_network__For_application_installation___damaged_file__may_be_reported_)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After some further investigation i found out, that the air app is deleting the downloaded update.air file right before the update application could start. The processmonitor tool did show some buffer overflow events in the Windows Event flow. I have no clue where they come from... -.- but it looks like the file gets deleted due to this overflow error. I hope i'll find a solution soon.